# What is the energy of a superposition of energy eigenstates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy-conservation

Suppose I have a system say SHO in a superposition of energy eigenstates $|{n_1}\rangle$ and $|{n_2}\rangle $ given by
$|{\psi}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|{n_1}\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|{n_2}\rangle $.

If I measure the energy of system there is equal probability of getting $(n_1 + \frac{1}{2})\hbar\omega$ or $(n_2 + \frac{1}{2})\hbar\omega$.

The question then arises where does rest of the energy go or come from? On one good day I measure system to be in state $|{n_1}\rangle$ while on other I measure it to be $|{n_2}\rangle$. It seems to me that it violates the energy conservation. Does this have to do with the measuring device? If yes then why do we never talk about it in formulating states?

Comment: Note that after you measure and get one energy or the other, the state collapses and now has that definite energy. I think you should be asking the general question of what the energy of a superposition is.

Comment: Yea that is precisely my question! The system could have collapsed in any one of the energy states. Then how come does it have exactly the energy corresp. to that state. Also by energy conservation one could say that the system had precisely that much energy to begin with i.e it was never in the other state.

Answer (score 18):

First, the energy expectation value of the superposition state you have written down is

$$ \left(\frac{n_1 + n_2}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\right)\hbar\omega $$

and one might naively conclude that therefore the energy of the state lies in between the energy of its constituents.

This naive concept doesn't work, though - the "energy" of a state that is not an energy eigenstate is not well-defined, just as the spin of a state that is not a spin eigenstate is not well-defined - all you have is the expectation value, which tells you what you would get averaging over many measurements. The spin superposition $|{\uparrow}\rangle + |{\downarrow}\rangle$ hasn't got a definite spin, and it is certainly not zero, although its expectation value is.

Therefore, the question *"Where does the energy come from/go?"* is simply ill-posed. A state that is not an eigenstate has no well-defined property "energy".

You might ask how conservation of energy is realised here, and the answer is simple and unsatisfactory at first: Classical conservation laws are realized on the quantum level as operator laws, or, in this case, as the conservation of energy expectation value

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\langle \psi \vert H |{\psi}\rangle = 0$$

in the course of the usual time evolution, which, by Ehrenfest's theorem, is always true for time-independent Hamiltonians. Thus, energy is indeed conserved.

The measurement process itself constitutes an interaction with the state $\psi$, and is in particular *not* a unitary (time) evolution on the system of the state. There is hence no reason to demand that the energy expectation of a state after measurement be the same as before.

Answer (score 2):

If energy is conserved, how so that a measurement of the energy of a state, such as
$$
\psi = N (\phi_1 + \phi_2),
$$
could result in two different energies? I think your question is easiest to tackle with the [consistent histories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_histories) interpretation of QM (though you'll reach similar conclusions with any other interpretation).

We must remember that energy can be exchanged between between the state $\psi$, the "subsystem" that made that state, and the "subsystem" (i.e. measuring apparatus) with which you propose to measure the state.

If we consider the whole system, state, the original process, and the measuring apparatus, energy is always conserved. Each possible (consistent) history of the state conserves energy - if the state has "more" energy upon measurement, it is because the process that made that state gave it more energy (though until measurement, the history of the state is undetermined).

In general, conservation laws, such as the conservation of energy, are obeyed by consistent histories for closed systems.

Comment: energy is not conserved because there is no fix energy in the system to be measured.

Comment: i sort of agree, though i find that misleading. i'd say that energy is conserved for every possible consistent history.

Comment: in the frame of standard QM the wave-function is whatever we know. A constant of motion is the value of that operator whose eigenvalue is our wave-function. If there is no such operator, our wave-function admits no constant of motion. Do you want examples? Coherent light. Consistent history, or Bohm interpretation, or many-worlds (there are many others) are not what the asker asked.

Comment: i'm honestly not sure what your asking/telling me? you're right, though, that the OP didn't ask for an explanation in terms of a particular interpretation, but consistent histories is useful for this kind of question.

Comment: consistent histories is an interpretation. Let me say otherwise, in the frame of the standard quantum theory did you learn of consistent histories? I don't remember this interpretation exactly, but I know that it is an interpretation.

Comment: @Sofia consistent histories isn't *only* an interpretation, in the sense that it comes with an actual calculation framework for reasoning about histories that is equivalent to--but structured differently than--'basic' QM. In particular it details certain questions that come up in things like this as simply *non-questions* that don't make sense and are purely the result of mistaken classical concepts. So questions like this can be tackled with an actual *logical calculus* that points out and corrects the error explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you prepare a state and you want to determine which state you have created. Of course a single measure tells you nothing unless you know *a priori* that you have created an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian. So from a practical point of view, a measurement is a repetition of the same experimental operations on a large enough ensemble of identical copies of the state you are creating. If you find that half of the times your state has energy $E_1$ and the other half of the times it has energy $E_2$, you can declare that the state you are producing is a superposition of state $\psi_1$ and state $\psi_2$, the coefficients of the superposition coming from the measured *statistics*.

Formally, the energy of this state is then the statistical averages of all the outcomes, which in this simple case is just $\frac{E_1 + E_2}2$, but in general is just the expectation value of the state on the Hamiltonian.

Comment: Let me rephrase what I think OP's question is. Suppose we have some superposition oscillator, *not* an ensemble. We can get one of two energies by measuring the energy, with equal probabilities. Suppose we get the lower of the two. Where does the energy go that would have allowed it to be in the higher energy state?

Comment: as I said the measurement procedure in quantum mechanics is of statistical nature. measuring something just once bears no information so it is meaningless. Hence why you need ensembles.

Comment: are you saying that energy is (clearly) conserved if one considers correlation between the measured state and the "system" from which the state was produced?

Comment: i think the problem of conservation of energy in this case is even immaterial. Once you have created a state you might want to know which state you have created, therefore you measure its energy. Which other energy is there to compare this measure with?

Comment: i prepare a superposition (i know my state is a superposition of energy eigenstates), then take a measurement of its energy. i can compare this energy to other energies I *could* have obtained from my measurement.

Comment: and how do you gauge your equipment?

Comment: @Phoenix87 No !!! I am sincerely sorry, but you are **wrong**, your answer is misleading, as simply as that. Didn't you read my answer? I would advice you to read it. In the double slit experiment the path is the $(slit1 + slit2)/2$ ? What you talk about? The situation is absolutely the same. It's a good procedure to read first what other people wrote. The energy is not *saint* it is undefined, as any other observable when it is not a constant of motion.

Comment: @0celo7 : Aaaa, I see what you ask. Yes, energy makes no exception from being undetermined.

Comment: This is explicitly incorrect. You cannot claim that the original state *actually had* a definite energy that was the average of the observed outcomes; this is a very basic point about QM. The superposition is *not* a probability distribution, and is *definitely* not some previous definite-but-unknown value that gets snapped to something else by measurement. Even the so-called "ensemble interpretation" isn't silly enough to claim this.

Comment: I'm sorry if my answer was poorly phrased. Of course I didn't mean that, but just that the observable energy has the average as value on the state given by the superposition, that is $\omega(H) = E$, where $\omega$ is the state from the superposition and $E$ is the average of the energies. It is von Neumann's idea to then define, from a practical point of view $\omega(H)$ as measurements on a statistically large ensemble of identical copies of the system.

Answer (score -1):

As you write the state $|\psi\rangle$ it seems that your system is in a superposition of $n_1$ oscillators and $n_2$ oscillators, each one of energy $\hbar \omega$. So, in the state $|\psi\rangle$ the number of oscillators in not fixed, and with it the energy is not fixed, it is ***not a constant of motion***. In this case the question where go the other oscillators is meaningless.

The situation is *analogue with the 2slit experiment*. The path is not a constant of motion, i.e. if you put detectors near the slits you can find in one trial that the particle passed through one slit, and in another trial you can find that is passed through the other slit.

Energy makes no exception, it may be no constant of motion as any other variable. That doesn't mean that if the measurement gave us $E_1$ before the measurement the energy was $E_1$. No, if the energy is not a constant of motion is wasn't $E_1$.