# Superposition principle forbids quantisation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, superposition, eigenvalue, discrete

Apparently bound states in quantum mechanics require energy states to be discrete. That means energy in such systems is quantized, right? However, say that we have a superposition of energy eigenstates. Using the superposition principle, I say that their average is a possible state, since we also say that there's the same probability that we'll observe each of the two available states. Then since this average is allowed, I can take the average of **that** and the smaller of the original states, can't I? And if I repeat this an infinite number of times, I should get something which is as good as continuous, right? If I talk about the $n$th energy levels of some system, I won't be able to express the energy each of these allowed states in terms $n$ without making some messy equations. Isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the energy of a superposition of energy eigenstates?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/164204/) Not exactly the same, but the discussion of expectation values should resolve this question.

Comment: On second thoughts, I don't think this is a duplicate. There is something to discuss in the difference between expectation values and superposition states. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be understood from a purely classical perspective, and it's a notion which appears in the discussion of almost any discrete variable. **The expectation value is not *necessarily* an allowed state**. For instance, even with a fair die, the expectation value is 3.5 (since it's the average of the possible numbers), but you'll obviously never get 3.5.

So imagine you're dealing with a superposition of two energy eigenstates $|n_1\rangle$ and $|n_2\rangle$. The question describes a long process of averaging the energies of those states and then using that average with either $|n_1\rangle$ or $|n_2\rangle$, but that isn't even necessary to get an expectation value of some arbitrary value in between the two 'allowed' states. In your discussion of 'averages', I assume you're talking about something like this: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|n_1\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|n_2\rangle$$ But you don't need to do that whole infinity-many-averages thing. You could simply consider $$\alpha |n_1\rangle+\beta n_2\rangle$$ where $$|\alpha|^2 +|\beta|^2=1$$ and choose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that the *expectation value* is whatever you want between $|n_1\rangle$ and $|n_2\rangle$.

However, in all of this, whatever $\alpha$ and $\beta$ you consider, you will only ever observe either $|n_1\rangle$ or $|n_2\rangle$. Nothing in between.

Comment: Why did you take square roots of 1/2 in the superposition of $|n\rangle$ states though?

Comment: The sum of the coefficients' _squares_ must be 1. Note the other equation $|\alpha|^2 +|\beta|^2=1$

Answer (score 9):

No. It is a good thought but no. In short, you are correct that we can prepare states whose *average* energy takes on any value between the lowest and highest energy state. But this is different than creating a state which is "between" the energy eigenstates.

Let $|n\rangle$ be the $n$th energy eigenstate. This means that we have that:

$$\hat{H}|n\rangle = E_n |n\rangle$$

and better yet:

$$E_{avg} = \langle \hat{H}\rangle = \langle n|\hat{H}|n\rangle = E_n$$

We can define a state:

$$
|\psi\rangle = a|0\rangle + b|100\rangle
$$

with $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$

$$
E_{avg} = \langle \hat{H}\rangle = \langle \psi | \hat{H}|\psi\rangle = |a|^20 + |b|^2 100 = 100 |b|^2
$$

Since $0<|b|<1$ we see that we can have a state which has any average energy between $0$ and $100$. In fact, since $|b|$ is complex there are already an infinity of states which have this property.

Suppose $b = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ so that $|b|^2 = \frac{1}{2}$ and $E_{avg} = 50$. This means that if you prepare and measure this state many times that half the time you will measure $0$ and half the time you will measure $100$. Contrast this with the state $|50\rangle$ where you would measure $50$ *every* time.

This is meant to illustrate the difference between a quantum state whose *average* energy is $50$ and an eigenstate of energy whose measured energy is *always* 50.

There are other differences as well. Suppose the system is a harmonic oscillator. In that case $n$ of state $|n\rangle$ tells you that the oscillator has an amplitude of oscillation of exactly $\sqrt{n}$ in phase space ($\hat{X}^2+\hat{P}^2 = \hat{n} \rightarrow n$ in the appropriate units). If the system is in state $|\psi\rangle$ above you will find it half the time with amplitude $0$ and half the time with amplitude $10 = \sqrt{100}$ but never with amplitude $\sqrt{50}$. This is another sense in which the superposition of two states is not really like the *average* of the two states. In terms of expectation values things can sometimes be similar but not always. Generally what you've described is not a good way of thinking about quantum states.

Comment: When you mention the state $|100\rangle$, are you talking about some random state with the energy of 100 (units)? Or is it the name of the state? If it's actually for an energy of $100$, then is $|0\rangle$ supposed to be zero-energy?

Comment: Yes, $|100\rangle$ and $|0\rangle$ are energy eigenstates with $100$ and $0$ Energy respectively. (Ignoring zero point energy in the case of a harmonic oscillator which contributes energy of 1/2 unit)

Answer (score -1):

As the Schrödinger equation is linear, any linear combination of solutions is also a solution. However, solutions have be normalised to unity, thus representing unit elementary charge. Furthermore, most of
these solutions are not stationary. Only solutions of the *time independent* equation are and represent discrete energies. Non stationary solitions can represent energies intermediate between those of the stationary states.

Comment: So I can have a wavefunciton evolve over time and eventually I _must_ be able to observe _all_ energies at some point of time or other?

Comment: No you will observe these only on average. A single measurement outcome can only be one of the eigenvalues.